# Prove that $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx$ is convergent, and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

There is a summary of functions, $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},\ldots$, domain is $[0, \infty)$, such that $$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x \in [0, n) \\
      \frac{-1}{n}x+1+\frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x \in [n, n+1) \\
      0 & \text{if } x \in [n+1, \infty) \\
   \end{cases}$$

Prove that $\int_0^\infty f_n(x) \, dx$ is convergent, and $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$. First of all, can I use a comparison theorem to prove this is true or not (but how do I use this, for a piecewise function?) Other hand, I can calculate the integral. But I don't know how to calculate a piecewise integral...Please help.

Comment: "But I don't know how to calculate a piecewise integral..." --- Have you already proven $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_a^c f(x)\,dx + \int_c^b f(x)\,dx$$ if $a < c < b$ and $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Can you explain? Thank you.

Comment: I know that property of integrals too.

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^n f_n(x)\,dx + \int_n^{n+1} f_n(x)\,dx + \int_{n+1}^\infty f_n(x)\,dx$$